# How to configure apache to support .htaccess files

Tags: apache

Want to configure apache to support .htaccess files. but not able to do.

How to do that ? for php application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By changing the setting:

```
AllowOverride None
```

to

```
AllowOverride FileInfo
```